# Why does the "kill" command work differently in bash and zsh

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

the `-L` flag provided in `kill` does not work in zsh.

When I run the command `kill -L` Using zsh the result is:

```
kill: unknown signal: SIGL
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

Running `kill -L` Using bash gives the list of signal names as expected.

```
-L, --table
List signal names in a nice table.
```

Please help me understand why this inconsistency, and can it be "fixed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is a shell builtin for both zsh and bash, with different implementations and options on each. The zsh builtin does support the POSIX `-l` option for listing signals, but not the GNU `-L` extension.

You can always use `/bin/kill` to run the freestanding program version if you desire. On OSes with a GNU runtime, that'll also support `-L`.

Comment: In Bash, never use `which`; use `type` instead. `type kill` will tell you `kill is a shell builtin`.

Comment: @wjandrea Really? I didn't see it listed as a builtin in the manual either when I checked.

Comment: It's documented in the job control section, not the shell builtins section. Will update answer accordingly in a bit.